# Ajax query string parameters null

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts-1

There is a delete button on UI and on click of that I have to call some service method which would call get some value from DB and I have to display that on popup.

I have to call a particular method of an Action class. So I am adding the task id and command name(method name) to the query string. But when in action class I do

request.getParameter("command")--> this results in null

Please found the javascript method.

```
function ajaxGetDependentTask(id)
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
        }
        catch (e2)
        {
            xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
        }
    }
    if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
    {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
    }
    var url = "/admin/TaskEdit.do?id=" + id + "&command=findDependenciesFor";
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServletResponse;
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Here I found that the form is getting submitted and the query string is coming as null.

Comment: if your form is getting submitted, then all the javascript you've put here doesn't even act at all... check my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But the issue is , I have only one form and there are 4 other buttons also and on click of those it should submit the form.

Comment: So make sure that your special button is just a button, and not a of type `submit`, and then when you click on it, it won't submit the form.

Comment: <input type="button" name="delete" value="delete" width="5" onClick='javascript:doDelete("<bean:write name="form" property="id"/>","<bean:write name="form" property="name"/>");'/>  --- This is the code

Comment: I don't know where the issue is.. :(

Comment: Without further information we probably won't be able to help. Check your browser's JS console for the actual request being made to sanity-check the parameters. Since you're using S1 you should be using an action form to get the parameters, it's possible S1's normal request processing pipeline is modifying the request; you can check in the default request processor, or your own implementation if you've extended it.

Answer (score 0):

If the for is actually submitted, then the request parameters you see on your server are the inputs inside the form, and not what wrote here...

You should use jQuery, and in the form.submit(), you should construct your own ajax call (example below), and don't forget to `return false;` to prevent the form from submitting.

You should use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for the ajax call, for the ease of use, and cross browsers compatibility:

```
function ajaxGetDependentTask(id){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/admin/TaskEdit.do',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      id: id,
      command: 'findDependenciesFor'
    },
    success: handleServletResponse,
    error: function(){console.log('something bad just happened');}
  });
}
$('#yourButtonId').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).val(); // assuming that's how you get the 'id' for your example code above...
  ajaxGetDependentTask(id);
});
$('#yourFormId').submit(function(){return false;});
```